# Get GWT DialogBox absolute position - onLoad/onAttach/show do not helps

Tags: java, gwt, dialog, popuppanel

I am stuck in getting an absolute position of `DialogBox`. I know it is the common problem (and strange workaround) for  `PopupPanel` (which is parent to `DialogBox`) to *set* it, but what if I want to *get* it, what is the exact moment when the box attached to DOM? Neither overriding `show` nor `onAttach` nor `show` does not help:

```
class MyDialog extends DialogBox {

    public MyDialog(. . .) {
        ComplexPanel vert = new VerticalPanel();
        vert.add("Test");
        vert.add(new Button("Close", new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                MyDialog.this.hide();
            }
        }));
        setWidget(vert);

        this.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

            @Override
            public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
                if (event.isAttached()) Log.debug("attach:"+MyDialog.this.getAbsoluteLeft() +";"+
                                                            MyDialog.this.getAbsoluteTop());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLoad() {
        super.onLoad();
        Log.debug("load:"+this.getAbsoluteLeft() +";"+this.getAbsoluteTop());
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        Log.debug("show:"+this.getAbsoluteLeft() +";"+this.getAbsoluteTop());
    }

}
```

So when I call `new MyDialog().show();`, all this lines do log `0;0`, however dialog is positioned in center of a page. But what I want is the sum of the chain of `offsetParent` positions. (And they are 0 in these moments even in JavaScript, if use JSNI to check this)

Again, `setPopupPositionAndShow` allows to *set* position but not get it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've got this to work:

```
@Override
public void setPopupPosition(int left, int top) {
    super.setPopupPosition(left, top);
    if (this.isAttached()) Log.debug("setPos:"+this.getAbsoluteLeft() +";"+this.getAbsoluteTop());
}
```

It gets the proper position and I hope it is the right way to do it and `setPopupPosition` is called every time. You will even call it manually when using `setPopupPositionAndShow`.

I think it will be wise to let this question stay at SO "for future generations".

---

**Upd.** If you plan to call `center(...)` or some similar method of your dialog, be aware that `setPopupPosition` will be called twice or more times (may be first time with `0, 0`), even if you'll check if it  `isAttached()`. Add some additional check to ensure that positions are correct in current call.

Comment: It will stay but you have to accept the answer even if it is yours :)

Comment: Yes, I will, but it is restricted to accept it during two days after posting a question (answer itself?), so I'll try to make it in a new year :).

Comment: really? never heard of that before. I accept mine right after posting them

Comment: It does, proof-pic: https://img.skitch.com/20111229-ef51s94qr173mpg682qss7cgf4.png and proof-link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: Thank you!! Happy New Year! :) (party)